# Adding or deleting item from a Set and the effects of hoisting

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I am learning to use Sets in JavaScript and noticed some odd behavior when going through the documentation.

```
let beverageSet = new Set();
beverageSet.add('Rum');
beverageSet.add('Tea');
beverageSet.add('OJ');
console.log(beverageSet); // returns Set [‘Rum’, ‘OJ’]
beverageSet.delete('Tea');
console.log(beverageSet); // returns Set [‘Rum’, ‘OJ’]
```

I know that hoisting pulls all variables to the top of the scope before executing code, but I have not seen anything showing that it would affect console.log()/methods called on arrays and Sets.

Is this an effect of hoisting or something else? How can I get around this and console.log() the full Set before deleting an item and then console.log() again?

Comment: I think you're seeing `console.log()` behavior that's confusing things. Are you using Chrome?

Comment: the first call of `console.log(beverageSet);` gives `Set {"Rum", "Tea", "OJ"}` to me

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome @Pointy, should I investigate console.log() behavior in Chrome to get to the bottom of this? I do get the same outcome in Firefox as well.

Comment: I also get the same behavior when using an array instead of a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `console.log` implementation sometimes decides to get the value asynchronously, thereby showing results that might have mutations applied to them, that really occurred after the `console.log` statement.

To avoid this, take a copy in one or the other way, for instance like this:

```
console.log([...beverageSet]); // convert set to new array.
```

See also Bergi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/5459839) to a question concerning the asynchronicity of `console.log`.

There is also a chromium issue on this: [50316 - Console.log gives incorrect output in Chrome Developer Tools console](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316). It might be an interesting read.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now, thank you @trincot. I will read up on this further!